# Можно ли транслировать из C++ в Haxe?

Tags: c++, haxe

Читал про Haxe - можно транслировать из Haxe в C++... Замечательно... А обратную операцию, из C++ транслировать в Haxe возможно?

Comment: напишите транслятор и это точно будет возможно. Но с++ достаточно сложный язык и я думаю, что это будет достаточно сложно.

Но если использовать llvm, то думаю все реально.

Comment: Это вопрос теоретический (можно ли в теории) или практический (каким конкретно софтом)? :-)

Comment: Возможно, есть готовые инструменты... Если нет, то нет...

Answer (score 3):

**Чисто теоретически** можно попробовать, но **практически** сейчас нет инструментов.

`hxcpp` в результате трансляции использует не все фичи С++, поэтому про вариант "просто сделать обратное преобразование" можно сразу забыть.

Но что важнее, если вы это сделаете, **непонятно, чего вы этим добьётесь**.

- Если ваша цель скомпилировать высокопроизводительные С++-библиотеки с помощью таргетов haxe, вы потеряете ту самую производительность, ради которой эти библиотеки вам нужны. Причём даже при компиляции через `hxcpp` вы скорее всего потеряете часть производительности за счёт "обёрток", потребовавшихся для фич С++, отсутствующих в haxe.
- Если ваша цель скомпилировать С++-библиотеки, достигающие своих целей путём общения с другими нативными библиотеками, то работоспособной библиотека всё равно будет только после компиляции в нативный код, кроме C++ у haxe других таких таргетов нет (насколько мне известно). А компилировать из C++ в haxe, чтобы потом обратно скомпилировать в C++ это очевидно бессмысленное действо.
- Если ваша цель скомпилировать С++-библиотеки без внешних зависимостей просто для работы под другими платформами, то гораздо быстрее переписать вручную все такие библиотеки, чем заморачиваться преобразованием произвольного С++ в haxe, т. к. С++ довольно сложен. А некоторые платформы-таргеты haxe (Java?) и вовсе позволяют работать с сишными расширениями, поэтому для них они в преобразовании не нуждаются изначально.

Comment: >кроме C++ у haxe других таких таргетов нет - [HL](https://haxe.org/blog/hashlink-indepth/), но он молод. Но он есть :)

Comment: @AlexanderKoz. ого, интересная штука. В Haxe Foundation устали от приколов Neko и решили сделать VM под себя? :D

Comment: Да, это одна из причин.